# Author capabilities: Deleting comments on their own published posts

Tags: user-roles, author, capabilities

I know users that have role *author* can delete their own published posts. But if someone comments on one of their posts, does the post author have the capability to delete that comment?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the capability by using [add_cap](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#moderate_comments). But as far as I know there is no way to do this only for their posts, so it would be for all posts.